# Check if a textbox text is a certain text

Tags: .net

I'm honestly very confused on what's wrong in this code, I believe I've done it correctly yet I'm still getting errors. (This is in Visual Studio 2019)

```
if CivilianName.Text = "Jeff" then
```

Anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: Could you post more code around this line? Is it VB.NET right? And please explain what errors do you see.

Comment: The code is private void SearchCivilian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if CivilianName.Text = "Jeff" then
        }

It is VB.NET and the errors I'm seeing are; Syntax Error, '(' expected, ) expected, ; expected, Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool', and The name 'then' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: No, this is C# not VB.NET the syntax rules are different. See answer below

Comment: Oh, I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like pseudo code, but either way, here's my take.  It may not apply as I have no idea what language you are using.

Most programming languages use a different syntax for 'assignment' and 'equality'.

An assignment looks like this:

```
Civilian.Text = "Jeff"
```

A test for equality looks like this in many languages:

```
if ( Civilian.Text == "Jeff" ) ...
```

See the double equal sign?  If you forget to use the '==' symbol, you are effectively testing an assignment.  The behavior then depends on the language.  In some languages, it will yield 'true', and in others it will yield an undefined result.

To sum up:

```
If Civilian.Text = "Jeff" then ...
```

That statement is NOT comparing anything, but rather testing an assignment.  It is equivalent to this:

```
Civilian.Text = "Jeff";

if (Civilian.Text == true) then ...
```

I doubt that is what the programmer intended.  And the absence of parentheses is suspicious...